# How to animate pacman mouth opening and closing in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, pygame, game-development

I want to draw a pacman which can open and close its mouth using python pygame.I'm unable to find proper documentation for that.

I tried this code to draw an arc and a circle back and forth, it works properly but the resulting shape appears like its not filled with yellow color properly as it gets when I draw just a circle.

```
def draw(self, screen, count):
    if count >0 and count <= 50:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,0), (int(self.pos.x)+16, int(self.pos.y)+16), 16)
    else:
        if self.direction == Vector2D(1, 0):
            pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 0), (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y), 32, 32),
                0.7853981634, 5.4977871438, 16)
        elif self.direction == Vector2D(-1, 0):
            pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 0), (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y), 32, 32),
                 -2.356194490,  2.356194490, 16)
        elif self.direction == Vector2D(0, -1):
            pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 0), (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y), 32, 32),
                 2.3561944902,  7.0685834706, 16)
        elif self.direction == Vector2D(0, 1):
            pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 0), (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y), 32, 32),
                 -0.7853981634,  3.926990817, 16)
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: i tried this code to draw an arc but the resulting shape appears like its not filled with color properly.
pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255,255,0), (int(pacman.pos.x), int(pacman.pos.y),width,height),
                    0.7853981634, 5.4977871438, 16)

Comment: if you have already tried and and does not work properly show your code

Comment: It seems an arc is a line, not a surface.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to me like it would work. Here's proof:

```
from math import radians
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30  # frames per second
MOUTH_EVENT = USEREVENT+1
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

class PacMan(object):
    closed_angles = radians(0), radians(360)
    opened_angles = radians(45), radians(315)
    color = YELLOW
    thickness = 16

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, width=1, height=1):
        self.pos = Point(x, y)
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.mouth_closed = False

    def toggle_mouth(self):
        self.mouth_closed = not self.mouth_closed

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.mouth_closed:
            pygame.draw.arc(surface, self.color,
                            (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y),
                             self.width, self.height),
                            self.closed_angles[0], self.closed_angles[1],
                            self.thickness)
        else:
           pygame.draw.arc(surface, self.color,
                            (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y),
                             self.width, self.height),
                            self.opened_angles[0], self.opened_angles[1],
                            self.thickness)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400), 0, 32)
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pacman = PacMan(250-25, 200-25, 50, 50)
    pygame.time.set_timer(MOUTH_EVENT, 333)

    while True:  # display update loop
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUTH_EVENT:
                pacman.toggle_mouth()
                continue
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pacman.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        fpsclock.tick(FPS)

main()
```

This is what the object looks like with the mouth closed and opened:

[[image: screenshot of pacman show two states[1]]

Comment: yeah its working. I'm also getting a shape similar to yours. My problem is those little black spots inside that yellow surface. As Michael Billaud pointed out above in the comments, I think it has something to do with the fact that an arc is similar to a line not a surface.

Comment: I suppose you could manually create two images in a paint program — one with the mouth opened and another with it closed — and then [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the proper one onto the screen after loading them both into memory.

Answer (score 0):

`You can access a Live demo with editor` https://codepen.io/wifi/pen/olKxE